# Unexplained RunTimeError while finding pairs in list of integers, whos sum is divisible by third integer

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime-error

As preparation for a technical interview, I was practicing Java problems on a platform for this specific purpose. This platform has a number of visible or hidden test cases, my solution passes all test cases with the exception of two of the five hidden cases. When executing these cases the platform indicates a "runtime exception has occurred" but provides **no additional information**.

My question is: **what possible runtime exceptions can you spot in my code?**

### Problem statement

The problem I was given was roughly as follows:

Given a (possibly non-unique) list of positive integers `nums` and a positive integer `divisor`, find the number of combinations of two different indices `i < j`, such that `nums[i] + nums[j]` is divisible by `divisor`.

Additional constraints:

```
1 ≤ nums.length ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ nums[i] ≤ 10^9
1 ≤ divisor ≤ 10^9
Memory usage: 1GB
Runtime: 3 minutes
```

### My solution

I created the following solution to minimize the runtime:

```java
long solution(int[] nums, int divisor) {
    long result = 0;
    int[] remainderCount = new int[divisor];
    Arrays.fill(remainderCount, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int r = nums[i] % divisor;
        if(r > 0) {
            result += remainderCount[divisor - r];
        } else {
            result += remainderCount[0];
        }
        remainderCount[r] += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

So to summarize, I am trying to figure out what possible issues could be occurring with my code and how can I prevent them or optimize the solution to not include these pitfalls?

I've spent some time trying to reproduce the error by creating input data based on the constraints, however the program never runs into an issue. I've also looked into a number of `RuntimeException`s such as:
`ArithmeticException`, `NullPointerException`, `ClassCastException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`,`NegativeArraySizeException`, `ArrayStoreException`, `UnsupportedOperationException`, `NoSuchElementException` but to me they all seem very unlikely given the constraints of the input. I can not understand this, so any and all pointers are very welcome! Thanks in advance :))

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer yes, 1GB, forgot to add that, sry

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't need the `Arrays.fill(remainderCount, 0);` line. Java will initialize an `int` array to zeroes anyway.

Comment: Not that it will help, but is there a link to the page with this problem at the practice / challenge site?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am also not allowed to provide verbatim materials or access any of the content in the future.

Comment: So, based on the comments following the (first) answer, the possible results are "Pass", "Fail", "Runtime exception", or "Time limit exceeded".

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nums` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

If `divisor` is less than zero, you will get a `NegativeArraySizeException`.

If `divisor` is zero, you might think that `nums[i] % divisor` would give an `ArithmeticException`.  However, a closer examination shows that if `divisor` is zero, you won't execute the loop body.

---

> ... and how can I prevent them or optimize the solution to not include these pitfalls?

These can be prevented with simple tests.  However, it is not clear that you *should* prevent the exceptions.  In both cases, they are due to the caller violating the input constraints.

It is also possible that there are other problems, but I haven't spotted them ...

**UPDATE**

When divisor is 10^9, `new int[divisor]` allocates 4 x 10^9 bytes.  That is a lot greater than 1GB.  So `OutOfMemoryError` is a third possibility.

Comment: Yeah I also found these possibilities, but for any of them to happen, the test case needs to break the input constraints that were declared.

Comment: So ... how do you know that is not happening?  Try checking those constraints to see if they are actually violated.

Comment: I doubt the platform would violate those constraints.  Even if it did, how would the O/P test? The platform hides the console output -- no `System.out.~` or `System.err.~` output will be visible.

Comment: @Stephen C, you're definitely correct, but unfortunately the output of the program in the hidden test cases is a blackbox so I can't review logs. I tried adding try-catch statements to change the output, but none of the information reaches me.

Comment: Be creative.  Catch runtime exceptions (selectively) and return a known incorrect answer instead.

Comment: I think you hit it with the **UPDATE** part of your answer.

Comment: The platform only reveals "passed" or "failed" for the hidden test cases.

Comment: Not so.  The OP has told us that the platform is revealing that a "runtime exception has occurred".

Comment: Ah, right. But, still the return value is hidden.

Comment: You don't need to know what the incorrect result was.  Just that it was incorrect.

Comment: You obviously don't have a devious mind.  You should read about ["covert channels"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_channel)

Comment: To clarify, when the platform says a runtime exception has occurred, it does so without showing any actual errors, it only makes this statement. Catching error did not change this outputting in anyway.

But yes, your update is probably the reason

Comment: For covert channels to be applicable, the actual execution of my code needs to happen on my device, right?
The practice platform executes my code on a back-end and only returns a minimal textual response

Comment: I maintain that "when the platform says a runtime exception has occurred, it does so without showing any actual errors, it only makes this statement" is sufficient to allow you to figure out what the exception was ... by a process of elimination ...

Comment: The "runtime exception has occurred" message >>is<< the medium that you >>use<< to encode one bit of information.  That bit represents whether you have eliminated a specific exception by catching it.

Comment: of course you're correct, unfortunately I don't have access to the IDE any longer

Comment: You can bet some of the test cases will have values that fall at or close to the constraint limits.  So, there is very  likely a test case that has a value for `divisor` that will cause your code to allocate nearly 4 GB.

Comment: *"unfortunately I don't have access to the IDE any longer"* - Well ... in that case ... you will never know for sure what the exception was :-)

Comment: Very true, so I will have to pay closer attention to these boundaries of my algos next time :)) Thanks for the pointers guys!